# Creating a custom styled WPF Checkbox purely in the code behind

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, styles

I'm trying to create a custom CheckBox control which will ideally be represented by a blue cross, which turns a lighter shade of blue when the mouse Mouse-Over event occurs, and fires a Click event when clicked.

I've seen ways of doing this in the XAML code using Control Templates and Styles, but not for purely in the code behind. I've created custom Styles in the code before and applied them well enough, but I'm having trouble with the amount of customization required this time around e.g replacing the whole checkbox with an image of a blue cross.

Does anybody know a standard way of a doing this? Can you create a full templated style in the XAML code, and then reference that template when setting the Properties on your new checkbox object in the code behind?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to do this, as it ruins the declaration approach with XAML, but there are times that you need to do it.

That being said, take a look at the `FrameworkElementFactory` class to build your XAML.  It's a pretty neat pattern.  The following snippet shows where I created a DataTemplate for a ListView in code.  I needed to dynamically add elements based on the number of days in a month for a time reporting application.

```
       GridView gv = new GridView();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string s in vm.DateList)
        {
            string column = string.Format("DisplayTime[{0}].Hours", i);
            DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();

            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(s);

            bool isWeekday = true;

            if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                isWeekday = false;
            }

            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath(column);
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

            FrameworkElementFactory gridElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
            gridElement.SetValue(Grid.WidthProperty, 60.0);
            gridElement.SetValue(Grid.HeightProperty, 94.0);
            gridElement.SetValue(Grid.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0));

            if (!isWeekday)
            {
                gridElement.SetValue(Grid.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(65, 65, 65)));
            }


            FrameworkElementFactory txtelement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
            txtelement.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
            txtelement.SetValue(TextBox.WidthProperty, 40.0);
            txtelement.SetValue(TextBox.HeightProperty, 20.0);
            txtelement.SetValue(TextBox.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center);
            txtelement.SetValue(TextBox.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
            txtelement.SetValue(TextBox.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right);

            gridElement.AppendChild(txtelement);

            dt.VisualTree = gridElement;

            gv.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn()
            {
                Header = s,
                //                            DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(column),
                CellTemplate = dt
            });
            i++;
        }

        ETCListView.View = gv;
```

Comment: I agree, its really not the preferable approach, but unfortunately its what we're stuck with in this current scenario (management overlooking etc.) The FrameworkElementFactory looks great for what I need, kind of exactly what I was hoping would exist in the Framework. I'll give it a bash and see how it goes, cheers!

Comment: This works great and gives me the control I need. The only thing I can't work out though, is which property actually controls the visual representation of a CheckBox. In the XAML examples I've read, its in the "Path" element. However, I can't see any obvious way of getting to that from the FrameWorkElementFactory, short of setting a custom template to it, which puts me back at square one. Any ideas / anyone come across this problem before?

Comment: I ended up cheating and using an Image with MouseOver and OnClick events instead, as that ended up having enough behavior to do what we needed. However, the experiments that I did with your code showed it worked very well, so thank you. Hope this helps someone further down the line.